# Blueimp jQuery File Upload returning html instead of json

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I downloaded the [blueimp Jquery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin, and outside of configuring it to use my server ( in js/main.js ) and changing the premissions on the upload directory it is the default.

When I select a file and click upload in chrome it says:

```
Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

In firefox it says:

```
Error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

I examined the difference between using it on my server and on the demo server, on my server in firebug the POST return is the entire index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin Demo 7.4
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
....
```

but on the demo server it returns JSON data:

```
{"files":[{"url":"http://jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/AMIfv97-LLxfuAdNifW5y8e1aHvb7HOkXdAC98NXM2Z_exEt27wxS5C4ZEzyd8BDGdZ8SHFQmbNquPIA7DIDvIMP60FvAxc6awXi--OF4z9OPbCCJquPG6hPyMyaheg9_mPpg_MdSQxuI-qczS6EFVSDOJ3qyU1AcrdM1O1WRKVNlD0gJhvYxuI/boot.png","thumbnail_url":"http://lh3.ggpht.com/HzbIhw7LOI7ltQJguWkvYCaQyNjnvkHTjbbxiZecFwi-pss98mjchv5KtoN_yVTqCvzwZj8WQHPB5u1BHOsZbxYPJBSf6XbxRg=s80","name":"boot.png","type":"image/png","size":172728,"delete_url":"http://jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/AMIfv97-LLxfuAdNifW5y8e1aHvb7HOkXdAC98NXM2Z_exEt27wxS5C4ZEzyd8BDGdZ8SHFQmbNquPIA7DIDvIMP60FvAxc6awXi--OF4z9OPbCCJquPG6hPyMyaheg9_mPpg_MdSQxuI-qczS6EFVSDOJ3qyU1AcrdM1O1WRKVNlD0gJhvYxuI/boot.png?delete=true","delete_type":"DELETE"}]}
```

Here is the modified section of js/main.js that I changed:

```
if (window.location.hostname === 'example.com') {
    // Demo settings:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
        url: '//example.com/script-location/',
        maxFileSize: 5000000,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        process: [
            {
                action: 'load',
                fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
                maxFileSize: 20000000 // 20MB
            },
            {
                action: 'resize',
                maxWidth: 1440,
                maxHeight: 900
            },
            {
                action: 'save'
            }
        ]
    });
    // Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
    if ($.support.cors) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '//example.com/script-location/',
            type: 'HEAD'
        }).fail(function () {
            $('<span class="alert alert-error"/>')
                .text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
                        new Date())
                .appendTo('#fileupload');
        });
    }
} else {
```

Other then that, the only other change I made was in index.html to have the form action point to my script.  There are no errors in the apache error_log.

I'm sure I missed something, but I can't seem to find it.

Additional information: PHP Version 5.3.20 /  Apache/2.2.22 (Fedora)

If there's any other relevant code that would be useful let me know and I'll update this post.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The server needs to make a JSON response and send it back. So when you invoke "example.com/script_location", the PHP code should return a well formed JSON. The file upload component has some sample server side code too: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tree/master/server/php

Comment: Inside of js/main.js it has url: 'server/php', which points to the server/php/index.php.  Does that have to be modified for it to work?  I look at it briefly, and it looks like it created a new UploadHandler(), but I don't see any errors being generated in there, and I haven't modified any of that code.

Comment: Since you have changed the "url" attribute of the fileupload component, just make sure that you put the UploadHandler functionality at "//example.com/script-location/" too.

Comment: I believe all the paths are set correctly.  I checked my access_log and see only the initial index.html hit when the page is loaded, and the POST after I click upload.  The error_log is empty.  As far as I can tell it never even gets to the php code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured it out, window.location.hostname that I changed to my servers name is *only* for the demo and has to be left alone ( or removed entirely ).  Not sure how I missed that originally, but hopefully if someone else makes this mistake this will help.

```
if (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.com') {
    // Demo settings:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
        url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
        maxFileSize: 5000000,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        process: [
            {
                action: 'load',
                fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
                maxFileSize: 20000000 // 20MB
            },
            {
                action: 'resize',
                maxWidth: 1440,
                maxHeight: 900
            },
            {
                action: 'save'
            }
        ]
    });
    // Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
    if ($.support.cors) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
            type: 'HEAD'
        }).fail(function () {
            $('<span class="alert alert-error"/>')
                .text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
                        new Date())
                .appendTo('#fileupload');
        });
    }
```

Has can be left alone, or removed entirely.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this block of code in localhost(xampp)**

```
if (window.location.hostname === 'localhost') //blueimp.github.io
{
    // Demo settings:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
        url: '//localhost/Upload/server/php/',
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        maxFileSize: 25000000,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(mp4|mpeg|mpeg1|3gp|gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
    });

    // Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
    if ($.support.cors) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '//localhost/Upload/server/php/',
            type: 'HEAD'
        }).fail(function () {
            $('<span class="alert alert-error"/>')
                .text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
                        new Date())
                .appendTo('#fileupload');
        });
    }

    // Load existing files:
        $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
        $.ajax({
            // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
            //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
            dataType: 'json',
            context: $('#fileupload')[0]
        }).always(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
        }).done(function (result) {
            $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
                .call(this, null, {result: result});
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply replace **blueimp.github.com** with your domain name (yourdomain.com).